# Field Audit Trail

Tags: security

Did anyone used Field Audit Trail to archive data in production? any experience/limitations with it? also is it part of standard licensees agreement or we need to buy something new like shield?

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=field_audit_trail.htm&language=en_US

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_history_retention.meta/field_history_retention/

Thanks

Comment: separate license I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=field_audit_trail.htm&language=en_US), the Field Audit Trial product is a separate add-on feature. It also comes under the [Salesforce Shield product](http://www.salesforce.com/uk/platform/products/shield/).

Interestingly, prior to Spring '15 release, you could ask Salesforce Support to increase the soft limit of fields to track from 20 to 50, without any issue. Whereas now, the increase to 50 fields to have field tracking history, is a feature with the Field Audit Trial product.

A ballpark cost (as of Q1, 2016) of having the Field Audit Trial product is ~ 10% of the overall net spend of the org.